# Validate UUID before insertion?

Tags: validation, rest, restful-architecture

My application has the following structure -

A user belongs to a deployment and he has a role(read, full etc) in that deployment. Each deployment then belongs to an organization.

I'm writing an API that will allow users to be added to an existing organizations.

While adding a user, it's upto the end user to send the `role_id`, `deployment_id`, `organization_id`. At any given point of time, a user can be added to only one organization, but they can be added to multiple deployments in that organization. For each deployment the user can have a different role.

Each of theses ID's are actually a UUIDv4. Now as the person writing the API is it my responsibility to verify each of these UUID are valid and belong to an existing organization/deployment/role, before trying to insert them? We have proper foreign key references defined on the database, is that enough? Problem with relying on foreign key is that, I cannot respond to the API user in a more meaningful manner.

Answer (score 0):

The server should check that all the preconditions for adding the user are met. *How* this is done is not a REST guestion. You can rely on database constraints, you can implement business logic.

The important thing is that the REST server must return the proper response if a user can not be added because the preconditions are not met. The HTTP status code for this is

```
409 Conflict
```

The body of the response should contain information about *why* the preconditions where not met. This information can be structured data, for example JSON.